# Why cant i write to a specific directory ubuntu firezilla sftp?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Im new to the whole server/networking realm. I currently managed to setup apache2 and mod_wsgi to serve my django site. I have created the project within /svr/ directory.

The problem is that when i try to upload new files or make a new directory i get a permission denied error. As far as i am aware i havent changed any permissions.

Using

```
ls -l
```

I get the following permission levels, is this correct?

```
drwxr-xr-x 4  998  998 4096 Jul 11 15:31 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Jul 11 14:26 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2  998  998 4096 Jul 11 14:23 folder2
drwxr-xr-x 2  998  998 4096 Jul 11 14:18 folder
-rw-r--r-- 1  998  998  248 Jul 11 14:18 manage.py
```

I connect via sftp using firezilla using the default username. I have not setup anything else (im sure this is a security risk but for now i just want to work things out one step at a time).

Why can i not upload to this folder?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

why user 998 has not a name? Maybe you just need to actually change the permissions: chown apache:apache /where/apache/writes/